# How the save the present date to use for the future record?

Tags: c, date, time

This code is printing the present date but I want to save it for future records like the amount was deposited on this date. How to do it and how to save it in a way that it could be used with other functions also?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
   time_t now = time(NULL);
   struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
   printf( "%d-", t->tm_mon+1 );
   printf( "%d-", t->tm_mday );
   printf( "%d\n", t->tm_year+1900 );

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a file and print via fprintf() into that file.